# Uniting rows calculating mean/sum

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mean

I have the following dataframe:

```
a=pandas.dataframe(col=["hschool","year","type","grade","stud"],[[0,2010,pu,5,1],[1,2011,pri,3,10],[2,2010,pu,2,3],[1,2010,pri,3,7],[2,2011,pu,2,8],[0,2011,pu,1,8],[1,2010,pri,0,2],[3,2010,pu,6,3]])
```

And I want to delete the "hschool" column and unite with different "year" and "type" values with the average "grade" and the sum of "stud".
I have tried using the following but I get both the average grade and the average number of students.

```
a.drop(labels=["hschool"],axis=1,inplace=True)
a = a.groupby(["year","type"])
a=a.mean()
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use `.agg()` on the groupby if you want different functions of different columns.Replace the last two lines with:

```
a = a.groupby(["year","type"]).agg({'grade': 'mean', 'stud': 'sum'})
#              grade  stud
#year type                
#2010 pri   1.500000     9
#     pu    4.333333     7
#2011 pri   3.000000    10
#     pu    1.500000    16
```

Comment: Thank you! @ALollz